# how to make an algorithm that has the lightbulb change no matter which switch is pressed in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

essentially, I'm trying to solve the following problem:

A lightbulb is connected to any number of switches. When any of these switches are flipped, the lightbulb will go from on to off, or off to on. No matter which switch is flipped, or the number of switches, the lightbulb will change its state.

let on = true and off = false

How can I code an algorithm that does this in JS

I tried setting up the problem and used propositional logic on paper. I set it up as followed:

```
     var lightbulb,
      switch1 = false,
      switch2 = false,
      switch3 = false;

function press(a)
{
 var a = !a
}

for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
  if(i % 2 == 0)
  {

  }
}

press(switch1);
```

I don't exactly know where I'm going with this, all I have is the press function. my loop makes no sense and I lost my train of thought. Been trying on paper for a long time.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array, because it hands over the reference to the object and an index for switching. Then change the `lightbulb` as well.

```js
var lightbulb = false,
    switches = [false, false, false];

function press(index) {
    switches[index] = !switches[index];           // change state of switch
    lightbulb = !lightbulb;                       // change state of lightbulb
    console.log('lightbulb:', lightbulb);          // show what happens
    console.log('switches:', switches.join(', '));
}

press(1);
press(0);
press(1);
press(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need every switch to modify the lightbulb's state, so create a global variable

```
var state = false; //Let it be off be default for now
```

Then you need a `function` to change it's state

```
function press(){
    state = !state;
    alert('Current state:' + state);//alert the output
}
```

And now create as many switches as you want

```
var switch1 = {
    flip: press //Keep a reference of press function into flip
};
var switch2 = {
    flip: press //Keep a reference of press function into flip
};
```

Flip the switches

```
alert('flipping switch 1');
switch1.flip();
alert('flipping switch 2');
switch2.flip();
```

Working example here

```js
var state = false; //Let it be off be default for now

function press(){
    state = !state;
    alert('Current state:' + state);//alert the output
}

var switch1 = {
    flip: press //Keep a reference of press function into flip
};
var switch2 = {
    flip: press //Keep a reference of press function into flip
};

alert('flipping switch 1');
switch1.flip();
alert('flipping switch 2');
switch2.flip();
```